# When you scroll the down do some action

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there any kind of script, that will do, for example:

some action on the website when you scroll down to some element?

Assume that i have a :

```
  <select id="1"></select>
    <select id="2"></select>
    <select id="3"></select>
```

And when somebody scroll down to id="2" do some action, like animation or wathever.

Comment: please do some research and post your trial code as snippet or on www.jsfiddle.net and we will be more than happy to help in your issue

Comment: you should used WowJs javascript library and ScrollMagicJs library for do this type of animation.

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery you could do something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).scroll(function(){  
        if( $('#2').offset().top <= $(window).scrollTop() ){
            // Do something here
        }   
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can used Javascript Library like ScrollRevealJs or ScrollMagicJs.both library are easy to used.